# Limit on bigquery insert api

Tags: google-bigquery

We are using bigquery streaming api for inserting data into bigquery. We found that in [google big query documentation](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/quota-policy) they have mentioned that throttling limit on google big query api is 10 / sec. Is this applied to insert api as well ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TableData.insertAll() method quota is 10,000 requests per second per table (see https://developers.google.com/bigquery/quota-policy#streaminginserts). If that isn't sufficient, a link for requesting more is on that quota page.

Comment: Thanks Jordan for the reply. I was also checking information regarding limit on number of tables and datasets. Is there any limit ?

Comment: There isn't a table limit per se, but there is an overall project limit at 100k per second. This limit can also likely be raised for certain use cases by contacting Google.